# How do I use ng-class with a css class that has a `-` in it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-class

I'm trying to use ng-class to with a css class called `has-warning`. The problem is that Angular seems to be interpreting the `-` as a minus and is trying to do `has` minus `warning`, which throws an error. So this doesnt work -

```
ng-class="{has-warning: form.name.$dirty && name.length == 0}"
```

How else can I write my ng-class? And no, I can't rename `has-warning`

Comment: have you tried putting it in single quotes?

Comment: it is simple javascript object, just quote your key

Answer (score 3):

With single quotes:

```
ng-class="{'has-warning': form.name.$dirty && name.length == 0}"
```